# PHP transaction commit OK but unchanged mySql database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, commit

I've got an issue with inserting records in mySql db from a php script. Here's my code :

```
// Set fields for post record insertion
$insertPostSql = "INSERT INTO tl_posts(title, city, city_id, video_url, thumbnail_url, description, longitude, latitude, user_id, category, hotel_id, restaurant_id, activity_id, creation_date, qualified) 
VALUES(:title, :city, :cityId, :video, :thumbnail, :description, :long, :lat, :userid, :category, :hotelId, :restoId, :activityId, :crea, :checked)";
$insertPostStmt = $pdo->prepare($insertPostSql);
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':title', $title);
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':city', $city);
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':cityId', $cityId);
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':video', substr($videoPath, strlen(ROOT_PATH)));
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':thumbnail', substr($thumbnailPath, strlen(ROOT_PATH)));
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':description', $description);
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':long', $longitude);
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':lat', $latitude);
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':userid', $userId);
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':category', $category);
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':hotelId', ($category === 'hotel' ? $categoryId : "NULL"));
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':restoId', ($category === 'restaurant' ? $categoryId : "NULL"));
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':activityId', ($category === 'activity' ? $categoryId : "NULL"));
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':crea', $now);
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':checked', $checked);

// New post transaction
$pdo->beginTransaction();
try {
    $insertPostStmt->execute();
    $pdo->commit();
    $response['result']['database'] = "Post added successfully";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $pdo->rollBack();
    $response['result']['database'] = "Error! Post not saved in database";
    die("Error! ".$e->getMessage());
}
```

It results in "Post added successfully response" but nothing is saved to the db.
Each value is OK I've echoed them before to test. The SQL syntax is OK too because it works on the database SQL command panel.
Basically, all fields are Varchar. types except the 'id' ones and the last two which are Datetime and Boolean.

I have to say that I was using this statement before and that this is working fine so the db is OK too :

```
$insertSql = "INSERT INTO tl_posts(title, city, video_url, thumbnail_url, description, longitude, latitude, user_id, category, creation_date, qualified)
                VALUES(:title, :city, :video, :thumbnail, :description, :long, :lat, :userid, :category, :crea, :checked)";
$insertStmt = $pdo->prepare($insertSql);
$insertStmt->bindValue(':title', $title);
$insertStmt->bindValue(':city', $city);
$insertStmt->bindValue(':video', substr($videoPath, strlen(ROOT_PATH)));
$insertStmt->bindValue(':thumbnail', substr($thumbnailPath, strlen(ROOT_PATH)));
$insertStmt->bindValue(':description', $description);
$insertStmt->bindValue(':long', $longitude);
$insertStmt->bindValue(':lat', $latitude);
$insertStmt->bindValue(':userid', $userId);
$insertStmt->bindValue(':category', $category);
$insertStmt->bindValue(':crea', $now);
$insertStmt->bindValue(':checked', $checked);
```

I'm curious about finding the final word about it. Thanks for helping

Comment: Note: You need to catch the correct exceptions, which is `PDOException` not `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed to find it adding each scenario to the functional statement (the second one). As long as I try to add a NULL even empty string value to one these it fails :

```
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':hotelId', ($category === 'hotel' ? $categoryId : "NULL"));
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':restoId', ($category === 'restaurant' ? $categoryId : "NULL"));
$insertPostStmt->bindValue(':activityId', ($category === 'activity' ? $categoryId : "NULL"));
```

It's not a problem because as they are foreign key they are NULL by default. I just have to make 3 different statements regarding the category case.

Hope it will help...

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that you are not catching error correctly. You have to be sure that PDO reporting level is ok.

Add these lines before your pdo initialization:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

You may also need to catch the correct pdo exception

```
try{
...
}
catch(PDOException $err)
{
...
}
```

I think it may be usefull